# MySQL query CASE or JOIN or UNION - which to use?

Tags: php, mysql, join, case, union

I have table of orders and suborders. And view which contains product rows. I want to `SELECT` all the rows with `status = 2`, but if the both (suborder and main order) have `status = 2`, I want that instead suborders id there was id of the main order.

This is example of my table:

```
| id     | suborder | mainorder | status |
|--------|----------|-----------|--------|
| 000001 |   (NULL) |    (NULL) |      3 |
| 000002 |   (NULL) |    (NULL) |      2 |
| 000003 |        1 |    000001 |      2 |
| 000004 |        1 |    000002 |      2 |
```

So the query results would be:

```
| id     | suborder | mainorder | status |
|--------|----------|-----------|--------|
| 000002 |   (NULL) |    (NULL) |      2 |
| 000003 |        1 |    000001 |      2 |
| 000002 |        1 |    000002 |      2 |
```

So the last one id changed cause of mainorder has `status = 2`. Order id `000003` doesn't change because order `000001` hasn't `status = 2`.

I tried this query, but I don't get how to include status..

```
SELECT
    CASE
WHEN mainorder IS NULL THEN
    id
WHEN mainorder IS NOT NULL THEN
    mainorder
END AS final_id,
 orders.*
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    `status` = 2
GROUP BY
    id
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in various ways.  The following uses a `join` to match only main order ids that meet the condition on the status:

```
select coalesce(om.id, o.id) as id
       o.suborder, o.mainorder, o.status
from orders o left join
     orders om
     on o.mainorder = om.id and om.status = 2
where status = 2;
```

If there is a match, then use the main order id.  Otherwise, use the original id.